# Custom style sheet for Orchard layouts editor

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'd like my website editors to get a more realistic preview when updating pages using the layout editor by applying the front-end styles. Is there a way to import a custom style sheet and have the layout editor apply it when rendering the preview? I've done this with the BodyPart (and html fields) by adjusting the TinyMCE configuration but can't find a way to do it with the layout feature.

Comment: There no out of the box solution, but it is a good idea to put recommend this as a new feature.